# Message Passing Algorithm and Implementation

Tags: trees, message-passing

I have a tree `T` with `N` nodes (Min-Span-Tree of a graph), and what I am  gonna do is to calculate for each node V<sub>i</sub>, the number of nodes reachable from each of it's edges (V<sub>i</sub>,V<sub>j</sub>). So after running the algorithm, every node of degree `d` will have `d` values each on a single edge shows the number of noded reachable using that specific edge.

Here is a toy example:
[image: toy example for message passing]

I can remember an approach to solve the problem, but I cannot exactly remember the name of it so I can find it on the internet. Here is a description of the approach:

```
1- Pick a random node
2- Treat it as root of the tree (structure the tree) 
3- Start from leaves and send 1 to the parents.
4- for each interleaving node (non-leaf), if it has received the message from all the childs, send the summation plus 1 to the parent.
5- Do the step 4 recursively until you reach the root.
6- For root set x = 1 + (sum of messages from all the childs)
7- subtract the incoming value from x and send the resulting value back to childs.
8- send down the value recursively while subtracting, until you reach the leaves.
```

Here are three steps of the algorithm for the toy example:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

and then send back info until you reach childs:

[image]

I tought the name of this algorithm is message passing. But I found many other message passing concepts but this one through my search on the web.

So what I am exactly looking for, is the name of the algorithm, the complexity, and after all if available a python package for this.

For the complexity I beleive it must be the same as the number of edges `E`, which is number of `N-1` so this should be `O(N)`.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  Are you asking about the running time of your algorithm?  As a function of what variable?  Can you provide concise pseudocode for your algorithm?  I had some difficulty understanding based on the English description.  Requests for software packages or programs are off-topic here, so please remove that part.

Comment: @D.W. I change the description, and I added some examples. Thanks.